# How to fit a sine regression curve of the form $f(x)=A\sin(Bx+C)$ to three data points?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression

Consider a sine function of the form: $$f(x)=A\sin(Bx+C)$$

Let's take a specific function: $$f(x)=2\sin(3x+4)$$

We can see that: $A=2$, $B=3$ and $C=4$

Let's take three random data points that would satisfy this function:

$$a(1,1.31),\ b(2,-1.09),\ c(3,0.84)$$

My question is: If you were given the data points $a$, $b$, and $c$ and knew or were told that they satisfied the above sine function is it possible to find the values of $A$, $B$, and $C$ by hand using simultaneous equations or another such method?

Comment: I think you'll have to add some extra conditions to have a chance of uniquely estimating these parameters, since it's possible to have $A\sin (Bx+C) = A'\sin(B'x + C')$ without $(A,B,C)=(A'B',C')$. For example, $2\sin(-x) = 2\sin(x + \pi)$ (and that's without the fact that $C$ is only determined modulo $2\pi$)

Answer (score 4):

This is very much underdetermined.  First, as @jld says in comments, you can shift $C$ by even multiples of $\pi$ without changing anything, and by odd multiples of $\pi$ if you flip the sign of $B$.

Also, you need fairly high precision on the input data to get any precision on the output. I coded up the example

```
> y<-c(1.31,-1.09,0.84)
> x<-c(1,2,3)
> f<-function(theta){
+   sum((y-theta[1]*sin(theta[2]*x+theta[3]))^2)
+ }
> newuoa(c(2,3,4),f)
> newuoa(c(2,3,4),f)
parameter estimates: 1.79124425810535, 2.975503348768, 4.12795969250191 
objective: 8.11726443214497e-14 
number of function evaluations: 815
```

so the  data you give are a better fit to
$A=$1.79124425810535$, $B=2.975503348768$, $C=4.12795969250191$, showing that the error in the inputs is magnified in the parameters.

It's also possible for the estimated $B$ to be much larger than the true $B$. Imagine a curve where the three points you gave are tens or hundreds of periods apart.  And it's possible for $A$ to be very large, especially if B is large, so the function shoots up and down in between your points.

Other sets of parameter values that fit fairly well to your points include

```
parameter estimates: -1.79127767472866, 2.97550833885794, 7.26952763781464 
parameter estimates: 1.79122067206457, 3.30768549218662, 42.9959126537192 
parameter estimates: 1.79120362015629, 28.4404292858858, 42.9958999928868 
parameter estimates: 199.787044280134, 3.14041642260686, 40.8484627595876 
parameter estimates: 197.829481291544, 28.2731459252784, 40.8485396248631
```

Comment: Asking for the **smallest** (in absolute value) solution $A$ ,$B$ and $C$ may make more sense, and is probably closer to what you had in mind.  It may not be easy to find, though.  In this case it is roughly $2,3, 4-2\pi$

Comment: Might be worth noting here that "underdetermined" in statistical models means [non-identifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability) of the parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure how much that helps. There are two very different phenomena going on here: the ability to add $2\pi$ to $C$ add get the **same** model, and the ability to to get **different** models to fit equally well to the same very limited data.

Comment: Isn't non-identifiability exactly that ---i.e., the fact that multiple different parameter values lead to the exact same likelihood function?

Comment: Exactly which? There are two different problems. One is a built-in symmetry of the model, the other is a set of very different models that just happen to agree at these three points (but not elsewhere).

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  But to the extent that the model is "underdetermined" *that part* is an identifiability problem (e.g., reversing sign of all three parameters, or adding multiple of $2 \pi$ to $C$, or going outside Nyquist range for $B$, etc.).